# How to do the code snippet animation as in Stripe Website

Tags: javascript, animation

In stripe website, when coming down the page, there is a code snippet that animates, generates as if someone is typing and running the code.

I checked everywhere but I never found out how it's done.
Can someone help me on how to create this ?

[Check out the Stripe website](https://stripe.com)

This is the picture for reference

[image: This is the picture for reference]

Comment: I think it's using something like typewriter.js

Comment: @Barmar Yes. It's kinda like that. But I wanna know the working logic behind it.

Comment: did you ever manage to figure it out?

Comment: Nah mate. I do know that they're doing everything manually through javascript